# In Silverlight, whats the equivalent of Itemscontrol that holds only one usercontrol?

Tags: silverlight, itemscontrol

In Silverlight, whats the equivalent of Itemscontrol that holds only one usercontrol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a ContentControl. Details found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: perfect. I feel silly and lazy. it is 2:30 am here though. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

ContentControl - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.95).aspx